# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to unzip the file using Expand-Archive in powershell if I pass the destination path as C:\Program Files\ I get the below error. however If I specify C:\Users\test\Downloads it works.

```
PS C:\Users\test\Downloads> Expand-Archive -Path C:\Windows\Temp\nginx-1.16.1.zip -DestinationPath  C:\Program Files\

Error:
    Expand-Archive : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\'.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Expand-Archive -Path C:\Windows\Temp\nginx-1.16.1.zip -DestinationPat ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Expand-Archive], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Expand-Archive
```

I tried passing '$env:PROGRAMFILES' and got the same error.

```
Expand-Archive -Path C:\Windows\Temp\nginx-1.16.1.zip -DestinationPath '$env:PROGRAMFILES'
```

how to pass the argument C:\Program Files\ as destination path to powershell.

Comment: could you try `"C:\Program Files\"`

Comment: you need to wrap quotes around the final path ... the embedded space makes PoSh think you have a new item. [*grin*]

Comment: silly mistake. its working. thanks!

Comment: Re `'$env:PROGRAMFILES'`: _Single-quoted_ strings never interpolate (expand embedded variable references), only _double-quoted_ strings do; however, in this case you don't need quoting at all: `$env:ProgramFiles` will do (with a _variable reference_, spaces in its value aren't a problem in PowerShell). I also encourage you to accept Matthew's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're having is you're using `C:\Program Files\` which contains a space, as such you need to wrap is as `"C:\Program Files\"` for PowerShell to complete.